# Customize JDBC query generation from JPA for select/insert/update/delete?

Tags: oracle, jpa

I want to route all jpa-generated jdbc requests to Oracle packages that actualy perform select/insert/update/delete queries. Is there any possible way to do this?

Update: there is no problem to generate Oracle packages for this usage, the problem is in customization of generated JDBC requests.

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing just that? Unless you receive externally generated requests to update tables (which I really, really hope you don't) you are in charge of all code so you can just change it to do what you want.

Comment: How can I say to JPA to generate "SCHEME.SOME_PACKAGE.INSERT_INTO_BLAHBLAH(BLAH BLAH)" instead of "INSERT INTO BLAH BLAH (BLAH BLAH) VALUES (BLAH BLAH)"